# Add Layers to an Existing Map Service Hosted on ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, web-service, publishing

We store our web services on ArcGIS Server and use ArcMap 10.6 to publish them. Is there a way to add new layers to an existing service rather than a complete overwrite every time I publish?

I have a MXD where I add 10 or so layers every time I an update, but need to keep all existing layers that are in the GDB, in the hosted service. It seems like a waste of time to keep overwriting the same 100 layers over and over again, when I just need the new layers added to the service. Am I missing something in the packaging/authorization step to do this?

Comment: Have you considered [Dynamic Layers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/publish-map-services/about-dynamic-layers.htm)?